# Accessing Citrix MDX in Ionic for getting user details

Tags: ionic3, citrix, hybrid

I have created a Hybrid Ionic3 app. It has been wrapped with MDX toolkit and is made available through Citrix SecureHub. The app can be downloaded and it works fine as intended. Now we want to build some role based features. As per the MDX toolkit documentation, there are methods available for iOS and Android to get user name - which we can then use to tie to roles and other user details.

I could not find any plugin for Ionic, wanted to check if someone has done something similar and is writing a custom Cordova Plugin the only option?